# How to write generic method for automatic type resolution on call?

Tags: generics, scala, types

Let's say I have function:

```
def foo[A,B](a : A, f : A => B) = ...
```

And I call it:

```
var x = new X()
foo(x, obj => ...
```

At this point it is clear that type of argument of lambda (obj here) is X (C# works that way for example).

However in Scala I have to write:

```
foo(x, (obj : X) => ...
```

It causes a lot of noise in code.

### Question

How to write my function foo to avoid such over-specification on every call? Or maybe I am missing something and adding type is needed because such call (without type info) would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think currying in general is the way to go, but if you have lots of functions with the same type of argument you could do something like this:

```
class Foo[T] {
  def apply[R](x: T, f: T => R) = f(x)
}

val foo = new Foo[Int]

foo(10, x => "Result: " + x.toString) // String = Result: 10
foo(10, x => x.toString * 5)          // String = 1010101010
foo(42, x => x + 100)                 // Int = 142
foo(12, x => Seq.iterate(x, 5)(_*2))  // Seq[Int] = List(12, 24, 48, 96, 192)
```

Answer (score 6):

Write the function as

```
def foo[A,B](a: A)(f: A => B) = ...
```

instead.  Scala treats each parameter list as a set of constraints to solve moving from left to right, and is perhaps overly cautious about making simplifying assumptions (e.g. the type of `A` might be a superclass of `X` the way you wrote it).  If you use separate parameter lists, it can break up the reasoning.  Also, it enables usage that is usually syntactically nicer:

```
foo(x) { y =>
  // Block of code dealing with y
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not marking your answer as solution (yet), because maybe someone will come up with answer without currying -- with short lambdas it looks "odd" :-) A cannot be super class of X, it is generic type argument so it **is** X.

Comment: @macias - You're mistaken about what generic types could work.  `foo(x, (y: Any) => 2)` is perfectly valid, and there `A` is `Any`.

Comment: This is because the signature of Function1 is `trait Function1 [-T1, +R]`, which shows T1 is contravariant (I think...)

Comment: @Rex Kerr, nope, you wrote type **explicitly**, and my intention is opposite -- to skip it. In such case type A should be the one as given in first argument.

Comment: @Luigi Plinge, you are right, could you please re-post your comment as answer? Thanks.

Comment: @macias What Rex is saying is that A _can_ be of other types. In his example, it is `Any`. Scala cannot infer the type of the arguments to function, so it cannot compute the upper and lower bounds for `A`, and, therefore, it cannot compute `A`. Here's another example of `A` being something else: `foo(x, (y: { def toString() }) => y.toString())`.

Comment: @macias - Anything you write explicitly which works could _also_ be inferred, potentially.  Since I was able to explicitly write something where `A` = `Any`, the compiler has to consider that case.  If you mean "the type of `A` should be determined by the type of the first argument", Scala has a way to encode that: use two parameter lists.  Otherwise, it assumes that the type of A should satisfy _both_ the first parameter _and_ the second, and rather than being adventurous and deciding to fill in the type of the function, it conservatively wants you to say what you mean.

Comment: @Rex Kerr, "say what you mean", I agree, but also I agree that defaults should be common-sense. Take for example rule of omitting type in declaration -- val foo = make_A(); theoretically foo can be A or its super class, but yet you don't have to write explicitly the type. However, the reason is not the rules of type resolution, but definition of Function1. Since it is -T, and not T, in Scala you have to specify the type.

Comment: @macias - I agree that it is the contravariance that means that there is no simple choice (e.g. choose the most derived class possible).